# Ionic 4 - How to configure a PWA to run on a subfolder?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, ionic4

There are enough tutorials on how to create a PWA using ionic 4 but all the solutions I found are focused on deploying the application in the root.
What I need is to deploy my entire application in a subfolder:
**https://my-domain.com/my-app/**

I explained in detail what's my problem in this repository:
**https://github.com/Viterbo/ionic-4-PWA**

Thanks

Comment: I'm in the same boat - looking for the same answer. Please help!

Comment: https://github.com/Viterbo/ionic-4-PWA here I describe the problem in detail and show a workaround I found to solve the issue. I hade to create a script to add it to the build process.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't address the Ionic 4 aspect of this, but I figured it out how to get a PWA to install from a subfolder, the answer is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#navigation-scope:

"If the scope member is not present in the manifest, it defaults to the parent path of the start_url member. For example, if start_url is /pages/welcome.html, and scope is missing, the navigation scope will be /pages/ on the same origin. If start_url is /pages/ (the trailing slash is important!), the navigation scope will be /pages/.

So, to run by itself (root folder), the start_url looks like this:

```
 "start_url": "/index.html?utm_source=homescreen",
```

but when serving the PWA from a subfolder, it looks like this:

```
  "start_url": "/app-folder/index.html?utm_source=homescreen",
  "scope": "/app-folder/",
```

I tested this on the latest Chrome on Windows 10 and the latest Android 9 release.

Comment: I tried this for a folder called starto and it doesn't seem to work for me yet.

I've set `start_url` and `scope` to both

 `manifest.json` and `manifest.webmanifest`.

I also set that folder to index.html to
`<base href="/starto/"/>`

It's also weird because Angular has a way to build for this that ionic seems to ignore: `ionic build prod --base-href '/starto'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's ewhat worked for me, First scope and start url should be same

manifest.json

```
  "scope": "/admin/",
  "start_url": "/admin/?u=what-ever"
```

service worker path should be same as scope
index.html

```
function onLoad() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/admin/sw.js')
        .then(function (reg) {
          console.log("Yes");
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log("No", err)
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
```